# Default logging lines from Flask @app.route decorator not sent to Apache2 error.out by WSGI

Tags: logging, flask, apache2, mod-wsgi, wsgi

We have a `flask` app running on `WSGI` using `apache2`.

`app.logger.<level>(message)` lines work fine from within the code. But, the generic logging lines that are produced by the `@app.route` flask decorator do NOT appear.

They **do** appear when the flask app is run manually, just not when run via Apache2 WSGI.

**How do I get the autogenerated log lines to be sent to the apache2 error.out log by WSGI**

I.e. Running manually

```
# flask run
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DEBUG in app [/var/www/APP/lib/python3.4/site-packages/APPNAME/app.py:34]:
Using app defaults, please provide a valid config file
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Serving Flask app "APPNAME.app"
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR in app [/var/www/APP/lib/python3.4/site-packages/APPNAME/app.py:102]:
TEST IN welcome(route)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TEST IN welcome(route)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
WARNING in app [/var/www/APP/lib/python3.4/site-packages/APPNAME/app.py:103]:
TEST IN welcome(route)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TEST IN welcome(route)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO in app [/var/www/APP/lib/python3.4/site-packages/APPNAME/app.py:104]:
TEST IN welcome(route)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DEBUG in app [/var/www/APP/lib/python3.4/site-packages/APPNAME/app.py:105]:
TEST IN welcome(route)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Aug/2018 14:44:45] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Aug/2018 14:44:45] "GET /static/css/selectize.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Aug/2018 14:44:45] "GET /static/css/material.min.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Aug/2018 14:44:46] "GET /static/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

**When run via WSGI**, the log lines in the code are logged to the apache2 `error.out`, but the lines starting with `127.0.0.1` that are created from within the Flask decorator itself **are not** getting logged to the apache2 error.out.

------------------------------------------------------------------

=== **Lines NOT sent to the apache2 error.out when run by WSGI** ===

```
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Aug/2018 14:44:45] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Aug/2018 14:44:45] "GET /static/css/selectize.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Aug/2018 14:44:45] "GET /static/css/material.min.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Aug/2018 14:44:46] "GET /static/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

=== The **WSGI.py** file ===

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding=utf-8
import os
import sys
import logging
import site

# The path of the APPNAME project directory is the same as the directory of this file
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
level = logging.getLevelName('DEBUG')
logger= logging.getLogger(__file__)
logger.setLevel(level)
logger.debug("Logging enabled via \"logger=logging.getLogger('" +  __file__ + "'\"")

site.addsitedir(PROJECT_DIR)
sys.path.append(PROJECT_DIR)

from APPNAME.app import app as application
```

=== The **APPNAME.py** file ===

```
from APPNAME.workers import filter_genes, run_analyse

this_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
app = flask.Flask('APPNAME',
                  template_folder=os.path.join(this_dir, 'templates'),
                  static_folder=os.path.join(this_dir, 'static'))
app.secret_key = os.urandom(24)
app.config.from_pyfile(os.path.join(this_dir, 'config.py'))
app.logger.addHandler(logging.getLogger('rq.worker'))

try:
    user_config = app.config.from_pyfile(sys.argv[1])
except FileNotFoundError:
    msg = 'Using app defaults, please provide a valid config file'
    app.logger.debug(msg)
except IndexError:
    pass

Genome.init(app.config['DATA_PATH'])
Regulator.init(app.config['DATA_PATH'])

conn = Redis(charset="utf-8", decode_responses=True)
# assert redis is running
conn.ping()

@app.route('/')
def welcome():
    app.logger.error("TEST IN welcome(route)") #3333
    app.logger.warning("TEST IN welcome(route)") #3333
    app.logger.info("TEST IN welcome(route)") #3333
    app.logger.debug("TEST IN welcome(route)") #3333
    return render_template('welcome.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(app.config)
    app.run(debug=app.config['DEBUG'], host=app.config['HOST'], port=app.config['PORT'])
```

=== The **wsgi.py** config file ===

```
# !/usr/bin/env python3
# coding=utf-8
DATA_PATH='/var/www/APP/data/'
SESSION_TTL=3600
RESULT_TTL=86400
REGULATORS_TTL=3600
MAX_RESULTS=100
SESSION_STORE="/tmp/APPNAME-{unique_id}"
PORT=5000
HOST='0.0.0.0'
DEBUG=True
TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD = True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request log is part of the dev server, in a production setup (or any other setup not using the dev server) it is up to the web server to log requests.

If you really want to log those yourself, you would have to implement it yourself, e.g. using a hook when flask tears down an app context.